# How to refer to the Vue component's this instead of the D3 this instance

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, this

I'm trying to update the Vue components data section, to ultimately force the page to update the component with new data.

The Vue component should update when the D3 svg element is clicked on.

I can get the event from the D3 element being clicked on, but I then cannot refer to the Vue instance.

I've tried splitting the function into smaller ones, to hang onto the this instance, but to no avail. I'm new to d3 and vue, but feel the approach of mixing jquery syntax unnatural.

```
export default {
new:"example"
data() {
return {
  showModal : false
  message : null
},
methods: {
   showModalAndMessage(){
   $('d3element').click(function(message){
   this.showmodal = true;
   this.message = message;
   console.log(this)
}
```

However, the above just prints the d3 this instance, how can I get it to refer to the Vue instance?

Comment: Did you try an arrow function? Also, not related: you do not need jQuery here, just use D3 itself for getting the element.

Comment: Did you try with this.$el

Comment: Trying with the arrow function now. Could you expand on the $el please?

Comment: We are two different persons commenting. If you want to address someone specifically, use a `@` before their name.

Answer (score 0):

To access the vue instance use the arrow function, like this:

```
export default {
new:"example"
data() {
return {
  showModal : false
  message : null
},
methods: {
   showModalAndMessage(){
   $('d3element').click( message => {
   this.showmodal = true;
   this.message = message;
})
```